# Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group. Show that $\chi(1) > 2$ for every nontrivial irreducible character $\chi$ of $G$.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group. Show that $\chi(1) > 2$ for every nontrivial irreducible
character $\chi$ of $G$. (You may need to use the following fact from elementary finite group theory:
if $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$, then there exists an
element $g\in G$ of order $p$.

I know how to proof if that: $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$, then there exists an element $g\in G$ of order $p$, but how I can used this hint to proof the theorem

Comment: Proof can be found in (Huppert 1998, [Proposition 6.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=GjyWI91FAZQC&pg=PA72)).

Comment: Thank you so much